# Flex DateChooser events for individual days?

Tags: apache-flex, components, datechooser

I'm using a DateChooser, and want to show different information in a tooltip as the user rolls over each day. Is there an event that fires as I'm rolling around the calendar that will tell me what day I'm currently over?

Answer (score 4):

It's a little complicated. You're going to need to use the mx_internal namespace. The grid portion of the DateChooser component is a CalenderLayout component in DateChooser.as.

```
mx_internal var dataGrid:CalenderLayout;
```

CalenderLayout.as has the mouseMoveHandler. In the handler we have:

```
var selCell:IUITextField = dayBlocksArray[colIndex][rowIndex];
```

that gives you the necessary info about which day the mouse is over. You will need to extend DateChooser to use an extended CalendarLayout that exposes the selectedCell.

perhaps:

```
private function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    ...
    dispatchEvent(new DayHoverEvent(selCell.text));
}
```

I guess what I'm trying to say is it's kinda tricky, and it uses mx_internal, which means the variables are subject to change in later versions of Flex.

Comment: Sweet exactly what i was searching for. I added a dispatchEvent to mousup instead of MouseMoveHandler as MouseMoveHandler was triggering streaming events of selCell.text.

Answer (score 0):

What about [`change`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DateChooser.html#event:change)?

Comment: isn't that only fired on click?

Comment: (or perhaps when the selected date is changed programmatically) -- I'm not talking about the selected date, only the hovered date.

Comment: You will need to have a MouseEvent handler as suggested in the other post.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out my blog post on this: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2010/06/displaying-color-coded-events-in-flex.html

I've based this on some previous work by Kevin Brammer (http://www.cyberslingers.com/weblog/post/Adding-Calendar-Event-Entries-to-the-Flex-DateChooser-Component.aspx) - it allows you to add a tooltip to individual days and colour code them

Hope it helps,

simon